# Git remote branches not listed

Tags: git, github, repository

So I'm trying to create a remote branch so I can push updates to a project I'm doing to my Github account, but for whatever reason, my remote branches aren't being created.

These are the commands I am running:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:<username>/first_app.git
git push origin master
```

After running the first line, everything seems to work fine and I don't get any error messages. BUT, when I check what remote branches I have, nothing will show. The command I ran for that was:

```
git branch -r
```

Ignoring that I figured I would at least try the second command from above. When I did, naturally, it says:

```
ERROR: Repository not found
```

If someone could help me figure this out it would be greatly appreciated. I've been trying to find information on this online but haven't run into anything yet.

Comment: Try fetching the remote: `git fetch -v`. Also the second command probably was `git branch -r` not `git remote -r`.

Comment: Yea git fetch -v origin just says ERROR: Repository not found...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After you add remote, git does not have any knowledge about remote branches yet. In fact, remote URL could be very well invalid.

`git fetch` command is designed to do the following:

1. Try to communicate to remote and get list of branches on that remote. Snapshot of this information is stored locally in `.git/refs/remotes/remotename` and is not updated until next `git fetch`.
2. Get all new git objects for that remote and selected branch (or all tracking branches).

In other words, doing `git fetch` is almost mandatory for you.

By the way, `git pull` = `git fetch` + `git merge`, so doing `git pull` will also accomplish what you want.

Comment: When I use the "git fetch" command it still replies saying ERROR: Repository not found

Comment: Just like I mentioned, remote URL can be invalid. Are you sure you got it right?

Comment: Can you simply `git clone git@github.com/username/first_app.git`? In other words, does github repo even exist?

Comment: It worked now...gahhhh. I did the git clone and it was there. I think the issue was the URL, like you had mentioned...but now when I attempt to push my project for the first time im getting a non-fast-forward error. 

I thought that could be fixed with git fetch, but nothings working again...haha

Comment: for non-fast-forward, you should either rebase or merge your working branch into github master branch. then you will be able to push

Comment: Great. I'll definitely do that later. Thanks a ton for your help.